# how to use @JoinColumn in OneToOne mapping in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

I have seen many questions asked on @JoinColumn and this concept was clear to me until I came across the following situation.

Let's consider mapping is OneToOne Unidirectional mapping. i have used following annatation in the parent class:
Case 1:-
`@JoinColumn(name="test_Id",referencedColumnName="refToPrimaryKey")` and  Entity class is not implementing Serializable interface. in this case program is executing without any exception.
Case 2:-
`@JoinColumn(name="test_Id",referencedColumnName="refToNonPrimaryKey")` and  Entity class is not implementing Serializable interface.

Here program is throwing exception like:

```
threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.homecare.persistance.resource.TestEntity cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.homecare.persistance.resource.TestEntity cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getKeyOfOwner(CollectionType.java:414)
```

Can you Guys help me out to know the concept why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using second level caching, As per caused show 
`cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getKeyOfOwner(CollectionType.java:414)`

As per hibernate doc, `disassemble` Return a disassembled representation of the object.  This is the value Hibernate will use in second level caching, so care should be taken to break values down to their simplest forms; for entities especially, this
means breaking them down into their constituent parts.

If you will check the org.hibernate.type.CollectionType package

```
    //This solution would allow us to eliminate the owner arg to disassemble(), but
    //what if the collection was null, and then later had elements added? seems unsafe
    //session.getPersistenceContext().getCollectionEntry( (PersistentCollection) value ).getKey();

    final Serializable key = getKeyOfOwner(owner, session);
    if (key==null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return getPersister(session)
                .getKeyType()
                .disassemble( key, session, owner );
    }
```

So you need to implement Serializable interface in your entity

Comment: Bushman i am not using second level caching. i just tried to use annotation @JoinColumn referring to non-Key column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find below code.let me know  if you need  any other information:
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class TestEntity imple`enter code here`ments Serializable{
     @Id 
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private int id;
     @Column(name="name")
     private String name;
     @Column(name="roll")
     private int roll;
     @Column(name="stream")
     private String stream;
     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="for_Key",referencedColumnName="roll")
     private List<TestEntityChild> testEntityChildList;
}
Chile Entity class
 @Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="testchild")
public class TestEntityChild {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="Test_id")
  private int testId;

  @Column(name="city")
  private String city;
  @Column(name="state")
  private String state;

}
```